# Changing a tabs content inside a tab

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-activity

I'm having some problems with the tabs in Android.

First of all i create my tabs like this:

```
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    search = tabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Search").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
    mealplan = tabHost.newTabSpec("mealplan").setIndicator("Mealplan").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
    shoppinglist = tabHost.newTabSpec("shoppinglist").setIndicator("Shoppinglist").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
    settings = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Settings").setContent(new Intent(this,NewUser.class));

    tabHost.addTab(search);
    tabHost.addTab(mealplan);
    tabHost.addTab(shoppinglist);
    tabHost.addTab(settings);
```

Now I want to have the ability to change the content of a tab inside a tab. For example if im currently in the search tab (the default start-tab) i want to programically change the content of search with instant effect. Earlier i was just starting new activities with the activitygroup but that ended up giving me stackoverflow all the time. I assume that was because i couldn't use finish() because that would close the whole program.

So as i said, my new approach to changing/starting a activity from inside a tab is to call the Activity holding the tabs, and make that class change the content of a tab. But how?

I've tried using the setContent, but the effect isn't instant and it kinda overlaps the default content from the tab. Can you help me? Let me know if u want any other code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class l9_taboacto extends Activity {
    TabSpec search,mealplan,shoppinglist,settings;


    TabHost tabs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();
        search = tabs.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Search").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
        mealplan = tabs.newTabSpec("mealplan").setIndicator("Mealplan").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
        shoppinglist = tabs.newTabSpec("shoppinglist").setIndicator("Shoppinglist").setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
        settings = tabs.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Settings").setContent(new Intent(this,NewUser.class));

        tabs.addTab(search);
        tabs.addTab(mealplan);
        tabs.addTab(shoppinglist);
        tabs.addTab(settings);

    }



}
```

good luck,

---

Im sorry, it looks I understood your problem in wrong way ,here you can find solution for arranging launching intents :

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory

Mohammed,